# Assertion failure error when trying to delete a row from a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, row, assertion

Sometimes I get this error when trying to delelte a row from the UITableView:

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]

and other times it deletes the row with not problems.

Here is my code:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
 forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
     [[self displayedObjects] removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


     // Animate deletion
     NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
     [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}
```

Comment: Please give more details on error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your *numberOfRowsInSection* is returning the wrong Integer sometimes when you enter the editing mode.

Comment: YES, exactly.The object would be deleted from the array but then before deleting the row numberOfRowsInSection is called again which then loads the array from disk again and give the number before the deletion due to a problem in my loading of the array. I put a break point at the numberOfRowsInSection and it is all clear now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure.. but try this (worked for me once)

First Animate the UITableView deletion, then remove the object from array.

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
     // Animate deletion
     NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
     [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [[self displayedObjects] removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    }
```